# Фильтрация списка в компоненте p-dropdown

Tags: angular, primefaces, primeng

Есть ли возможность как-то изменять поведение фильтрации выпадающего списка? Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при вводе в строку поиска фильтрация начиналась со второго элемента, т.е. 1-й элемент (`{ name: "STATIC", code: null }`) всегда должен присутствовать в выпадающем списке, даже если введенное значение не найдено.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [filter]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity1" placeholder="Select a City"
optionLabel="name" [showClear]="true"></p-dropdown>
```

Компонент:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  cities: City[];

  constructor() {
    this.cities = [
      { name: "STATIC", code: null },
      { name: "New York", code: "NY" },
      { name: "Rome", code: "RM" },
      { name: "London", code: "LDN" },
      { name: "Istanbul", code: "IST" },
      { name: "Paris", code: "PRS" }
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я проверил всю документацию p-dropdown и не нашел ничего подобного. но эту проблему можно решить таким не хорошим способом. Вам нужно заменить логику фильтрации в вашем компоненте как показоно в примере.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-yrjncg?file=src/app/app.component.ts